# What type of optimization problem is this? Ride sharing?

Tags: discrete-optimization, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming

I am given source containers $s_1,s_2, \dots, s_n$, products $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_m$ and an assignment of which container needs to be used to make a certain product, which I represent as follows

\begin{array}
.&p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5\\
s_1&1&0&0&0&1\\
s_2&1&0&0&0&1\\
s_3&0&1&0&0&0\\
s_4&0&1&0&1&0\\
s_5&1&0&1&1&1\\
s_6&1&0&1&0&1\\
&&&\dots\\
\end{array}

where

- $1$ indicates it should be made.
- $0$ indicates it should not be made.

A source is not used up when making a product. The rules are:

- Sources that make the same products can be use in a single process to create the products.
- Only integer multiples of $k$, for sake of this example let's say $2$, sources can be used in the production process at the same time.

So in this example case, we could produce $p_1$ and $p_5$ in a single step for $s_1,s_2,s_5,s_6$ and then produce $p_3$ for $s_5,s_6$ in another or alternatively produce $p_1$ and $p_5$ in a single step for $s_1,s_2$ and then $p_1,p_3,p_5$ for $s_5,s_6$.

The goal is to have a low number of production steps. In a typical case,

- $k$ is $96$ or $384$ (not necessarily the same for every product).
- $n$ is around $1000$.
- $m$ is around $10$.

My questions are:

1. What type of problem is this? Can it maybe be modeled as a ride sharing problem? Some kind of matching problem? Bin packing?
2. What are sources to get started on this type of problem? I have done some discrete optimization (LP, genetic algorithms)
3. A heuristic approach that gives a local optimum would be fine.
4. Runtime constraints: shouldn't take longer than 5 minutes, absolute maximum 1 hour on a high end 2018 laptop (4 cores)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to produce multiple units of the various products (with specified demands). You might be able to get a good (but not necessarily optimal) solution by mimicking a one-dimensional cutting stock problem. In your case, your master problem would have a demand constraint for each product and a variable for each "pattern". (Each of your examples above, e.g. "produce $p_1$ and $p_5$ in a single step for $s_1$, $s_2$", would be a pattern.) Each pattern would contribute one per use to the objective function (number of production steps, to be minimized).

In addition to the master problem, you would need a subproblem to generate patterns that met the "multiple of $k$" criterion. The classic Gilmore-Gomory algorithm for the 1-d cutting stock problem used an LP to generate patterns, but I think your subproblem would need to be an integer program, which could make the one hour limit dicey (and the five minute target very dicey). I suppose you could try a heuristic (such as a genetic algorithm) for pattern generation, with a tight time limit, and just live with the possibility that it might miss some good patterns and lead you to terminate prematurely.

Comment: Maybe I need to think about this for a bit but I´m not sure I understand how to get the patterns right now short of enumerating them completely (which is obviously not an option).

Comment: The general idea is that the dual solution of the LP relaxation of the master problem is used to assign a reduced cost to each pattern, and your subproblem then looks for the pattern with the most negative reduced cost. It would be valid (maybe faster, maybe slower, but not wrong) to grab the first pattern with a negative reduced cost that you came across. As to how to do it, I might be tempted to try constraint programming, but it could also be an IP model.